# Problems setting a cookie from a machine proxied by nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cookies

For a project of mine,  I need to wire up a long chain of machines that are essentially proxying the HTTP requests for each other. It goes like this:

Web client - A - B/C -  D

When a request is made from the browser,  it first goes through a thin PHP proxy layer,  located on the local machine of the user,  whose purpose is to resolve complications with cross domain requests and so on. It proxies to machine B - just an nginx instance,  which rewrites the URL and proxies to C. C does some necessary modifications,  before proxying to D,  obtaining the response,  and returning it back to the web client. D is a remote service API which cannot be touched.

I have problems setting up a session cookie on machine C,  which gets all the way down to the original request. Although setting the cookie is possible,  when a new request is there,  it is not visible in Chrome network inspector,  and node C returns a nullpointerexception when I try to get a value from the apparently nonexistent cookie.

I suppose,  it boils down to tweaking the way nginx proxies the requests.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have following settings in nginx configuration at C in server {} block:

```
    proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header  P3P;
```

that would be enough to pass cookies.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the PHP side, not passing cookies around, via curl_php